# Validation function with return value 0

Tags: php, passwords

im busy with a school project and i made a function that checks if a password is valid. For some reason it returns "0". I have no clue why. Is there anyone who could help me out here?

I also made functions to check Mail and Username, those work fine.
Thanks in advance for your help!

```
function checkPassword($pass){
    if (strlen($pass) < 6) {
        return "Your password must contain more than 6 characters";
    }
    else {
        if (preg_match('~[0-9]~', $pass)){

            if (preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}_-]+$/u', $pass)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return "Your password contains illegal characters";
            }
        }
        else {
            return "Your password must contain at leas one number";
        }
    }
}

$val3 = checkPassword($_POST['password']);
if ($val3 !== true) {
    $_SESSION["wrongreg"] = $val3; // $val3 = 0, for some reason.
    header('Location: register.php');
}
```

Comment: Returning 0 just means the function executed without any problems.

Comment: The code you show... could not possibly return a `0`. It would return a `1` (if echo'd), or a string. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

As IncredibleHat said, it can't return 0. However, you actually do not show where you print the $_SESSION["wrongreg"] data. You instead redirect with header(). The only explanation to why you could say it tells you the respons is 0, is that something happens on the "register.php" page, which you haven't showed here yet.

One thing you might be doing on that page is: strval(intval($_SESSION["wrongreg"]));

That would give us 0 (but it is a strange thing to do). More probable is that there is some entirely different code on the **register.php** page, that gets in the way, making the script print something entirely different than the return string from that password function.